# Store supervisord config in the project's version control?

Tags: version-control, supervisord

My web project needs some services (processes) that are managed by [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).
I thought it would be handy if the supervisord config files for the services would be version controlled, so that they won't get lost and one does not have to re-build those.
I would store them - together with my project files - in a repository. And symlink the files into the `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` directory.

However, as some of the config options take absolute file paths (i.e. `command` or `stdout_logfile`), I falter to save them in version control.

What's the best way to go here?

Comment: Could you mention what those applications run on? Python?